# Perl - How to parse null values in a .tsv file

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, csv

I'm using Perl to parse an Excel spreadsheet which I've converted to a tab-delimited text file. 
I want to write an **if** loop that hinges on the presence of a value in a certain column but null values cause my code to fail.

Here's what the tsv file looks like:

```
Patient No.     Date      Freezer   Location        Description     Frozen @ Passage
PT101           12/29/09  F1,-130   P-3,68          SERUM                                   
PT101           2/16/10   F1,-130   Q-9,62          Omentum         4                                       
PT101           2/16/10   F1,-130   Q-9,63          Omentum         4                                       
PT101                     F1,-130   O-3,8           L Ovary Tumor
```

Notice that some of the rows have empty cells

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file = shift @ARGV;
open( FILE, $file );
while (<FILE>) {
    my $line = $_;
    chomp $line;
    my @c = split( "\t", $line );
    my $p = $c[5];
    if ( $p !~ /\d/ ) { next; }    # this value will be a number if it is present
    print "$line\n";
}
close FILE;
```

When I run this I get an Error Message complaining about uninitiated values confusing the Regex if statement. If there an **if** statement that I can use to check for uninitiated values? Is there some other way to write an **if** statement that is based on the presence of a value in the 6th column?

Note: I have considered using the **pop** function to get the right-most value and checking if the value is a number but this undesirable because there are more columns to the right of those in my example which are sometimes numerical, sometimes textual and sometimes blank.

Comment: Note that you can read the Excel directly (with the proper CPAN module), avoiding the conversion to CSV

Comment: Don't use regexes for this.  Use the Text::CSV or Text::CSV_XS module.

Comment: @Slavatron It would be safer to simply [save the spreadsheet as a CSV](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-HP010099725.aspx#BMexport).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I[s] there an if statement that I can use to check for uninitiated values? Is there some other way to write an if statement that is based on the presence of a value in the 6th column?

There are numerous ways you can do this. You can use an "undefined-or" operator (`//`)

```
next unless ( $p // '' ) =~ /\d/;
```

Or you can just check for definedness:

```
next unless defined( $p ) && $p =~ /\d/;
```

If it weren't the case that `'0'` is a valid digit-string, you could simply check for "falseness", like so:

```
next unless $p && $p =~ /\d/;
```

However, I thought I'd try to show you how to do this with `Text::CSV`:

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({ sep_char => "\t" });    
while ( my $line = <FILE> ) {
    chomp $line;
    next unless $line;
    die $csv->error_diag 
        unless $csv->parse( $line )
        ;
    next unless defined( my $p = ( $csv->fields )[5] );
    next unless $p =~ /\d/;
    say $line;
}
```